# What's wrong with my SQL Case command?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT *
FROM booking  
CASE
WHEN Travel_Date <= getDate() THEN 'Past Travel
ELSE 'Future'
END AS 'Has travel happened'
```

Comment: You need to change the `getDate()` into `CURDATE()`, see my answer.

Comment: And include the close quote after `'Past Travel`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *, 
  CASE 
    WHEN Travel_Date <= CURDATE() THEN 'Past Travel' 
    ELSE 'Future' 
  END AS 'Has travel happened' 
FROM booking
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I now have this error. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '<'.